# List items not sitting nicely in nav bar

Tags: html, css

Below is the link to the working navbar

the problem i am having is in the list item teams they dont sit below each other like the other list items . i know its because some of the team names are 2 & 3 lines im not sure how i can set them up so they sit below each other without all the space

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elroyz/SsNXR/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">


<ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Franchises</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">elroyz Xpress</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Skye Stickbeetles</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hortons Heroes</a></li>
        <li><a href="">The Predators</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> The Greater Western Sandhurst Storm</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stockyzladz</a></li>
        <li><a href="">General Soreness</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Wild Things</a></li>
        <li><a href="">The Bombsquad</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Chubby Chaser</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Soup-A-Stars</a></li>
        <li><a href="">StayClassy FC</a></li>
        <li><a href="">The Peptides</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Untouchable Saints</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Langy All Blacks</a></li>
        <li><a href="">McQueenMachine</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Fixtures</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Round 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 20</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 21</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 22</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 23</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Free Agents</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Adelaide</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Brisbane</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Carlton</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Collingwood</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Essendon</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fremantle</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Geelong</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gold Coast</a></li>
        <li><a href="">GWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hawthorn</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Melbourne</a></li>
        <li><a href="">North Melbourne</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Port Adelaide</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Richmond</a></li>
        <li><a href="">St Kilda</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sydney</a></li>
        <li><a href="">West Coast</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Western Bulldogs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li> <a href="#">De-Listings</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    width:100%;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index:99;
    background-color:#F00;
    text-align:left;}

.navbar {

    padding:0;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    border-right: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
    border-left: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

    .navbar li  {
            width: 100px;  
            float: left;  
            text-align: center;  
            list-style: none;  
    font: normal bold 11px Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #F00
                        }

.navbar a   {                           
        padding: 7px 0;  
        border-left: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        border-right: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        text-decoration: none;  
        color: white; 
        display: block;


        }

 .navbar li:hover, a:hover {
     background-color: #900;
 } 

.navbar li ul   {
        display: none;  
        width: 300px;                                   
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;             
        }               

.navbar li:hover ul     {
                        display: block; 
                        }

.navbar li ul li {background-color: #a4a4a4;
}

.navbar li ul li a  {
        border-left: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        border-right: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        border-top: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        }

.navbar li ul li a:hover    {background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `height:35px;` to `.navbar li ul li a`

Answer (score 0):

Add this property `clear:left` to `.navbar li ul li`

Like this :

```
.navbar li ul li {
    background-color: #a4a4a4;
    clear:left;
}
```

Result : http://jsfiddle.net/SsNXR/2/